# Copy elements or nodes to another structure using xquery

Tags: xml, xquery

How can we copy elements from one path to another path in different node tree/document using xquery.

for e.g. If we call below copy function,it should copy element(if exists) from path specified in $source-path to target-path

```
$source-xml:=doc("some.xml") 
$target-xml:=<element/>
$source-path:='data/records/record/columns/column1"
$target-path:='elements/rows/row/fields/field1"  
copy($source-xml,$source-path,$target-xml,$target-path)
```

Comment: This will probably have to be implementation-dependent. What XQuery processor are you using?

Comment: We are using Saxon XQuery processor.

Comment: What if `target-path` doesn't exist? Should `copy` copy `column1`, or just `column1`'s children?